# Как организовать базу данных mysql для почасового бронирования

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, структуры-данных

Помогите правильно организовать базу данных mysql для почасового или получасового бронирования помещение. Помещения открыты для бронирования на определённый период. Например с 8:00 до 23:00. И для каждого помещения период разный. Сайт пишу на PHP. На сайте будет выводиться время доступное для для бронирования. Подскажите пожалуйста. Буду благодарен.

Comment: Любопытный вопрос - проектирование базы - один из важнейших моментов создания ресурса - на пальцах подсказывать? Есть разраб, который в курсе всех нюансов - а здесь это будет шарообразный конь в вакууме. Имхо, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно вас понял, то первое что в голову приходит:
Есть помещение А, которое может быть доступно например с 08:00 до 18:00

Сегодня 30.10.2019 08:00 - это в timestamp 1572422400

30.10.2019 18:00 - это 1572458400

Имеем диапазон времени.

Клиент бронит себе время с 09:00 до 12:00 (в timestamp это с 1572426000 по 1572436800)
Другой клиент бронит с 11:00 до 12:00 (это с 1572433200 по 1572436800)

Перебираете все брони на помещение и проверяете время старта (1572433200) на то, есть ли бронь с временем установленным раньше (находим первую бронь), и сравниваем дату начала второй брони с временем окончания первой, т.к. время окончания первой брони позже, то бронь невозможна.

p.s. вариантов реализации много, это только пример логики